# Read body only loads if i cancel the loading HTTP request Post

Tags: java, http, sockets, request, http-post

So i having this problem tha when i have to read the body to get the data it only read the body once i cancelled the loading and it sends the mail

for the moment i have it works but not as i expected because i want to read the body without having to cancel the loading from the page

```
private String readBody(int length) throws Exception {
        debug("COMENSANT LLEGIR BODY");
        String line;
        while((line=readLine())!=null) {
            debug("LINEA->>"+line);
            if(line.length()==length) {
                debug("Sortint del while ja que line->"+line);
                break;
            }
        }   
        debug("ACABANT LLEGIR BODY");
        return line;
    }
```

Comment: A HTTP body is not guaranteed to end with a  newline character or even include one. Using readLine is the wrong way to read the body, you have to read it as byte stream until length is reached.

Comment: thanks for the comment i have find the error

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to get the body it's to read the byte and the convert all the byte into chars and get the stringvaluof()

```
 char[] bodyChar=new char[length];  
 while ((n=in.read()) != -1) {
    bodyChar[contador]=(char)n.byteValue();
            contador++;
            if(contador==length) {break;}
        }
        
        line=String.valueOf(bodyChar);
```